# Swapping quantifiers

Tags: logic, soft-question, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

In his book "Analysis 1", Terence Tao writes:

> Swapping two “for all”
>   quantifiers is harmless: a statement such as
>
> "For all real numbers a, and for all real numbers b, we have (a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2"
>
> is logically equivalent to the statement
>
> "For all real numbers b, and for all real numbers a, we have (a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2"
>
> (why? The reason has nothing to do with whether the identity (a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2 is actually true or not).

Concerning this kind of exercises I find it difficult to explain why this is true. What would be a correct solution to this exercise? For me it is clear, but I don't know how to prove it. Isn't it obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say it's obvious, and I think that's right; of course, the problem is how to *prove* it, as you say.

I think for this purpose it's best to think in terms of counterexamples.

Take the sentence "$\forall x\forall y(x+y$ is even$)$". Clearly this is false (in the integers), because *there is a counterexample*: for instance, "$x=3$, $y=1$."

Now consider the "swapped" version "$\forall y\forall x(x+y$ is even$)$". Then $y=1, x=3$ is a counterexample again - in fact, it's really the same counterexample!

My point is that any counterexample to $\forall x\forall y P(x, y)$ is also a counterexample to $\forall y\forall x P(x, y)$. Maybe for niceness you rearrange how you write it - e.g. you tell me the value of the first variable first, and the second variable second - but it's still really the same counterexample.

So what? Well, *a universal sentence is true iff it has no counterexamples!* So saying

> "$\forall x\forall y P(x, y)$" and "$\forall y\forall x P(x, y)$" have the same counterexamples

is the same as saying

> "$\forall x\forall y P(x, y)$" and "$\forall y\forall x P(x, y)$" are either both true (no counterexamples) or both false (some counterexample(s), which breaks each).

---

So how does this help you prove it?

Well, you're asking how to prove a basic fact about logic, which means we need to dig into the messy details of exactly how we *axiomatize* logic in the first place. There are many equivalent ways of doing this, so it's impossible to give a precise answer without first specifying a system, but in most of these the argument goes roughly as follows:

- Suppose for contradiction that $\forall x\forall y P(x, y)$ is true but $\forall y\forall x P(x, y)$ is false.
- Since $\forall y\forall x P(x, y)$ is false, there exists a counterexample: $y=a, x=b$.
- But then $x=b, y=a$ is a counterexample to $\forall x\forall y P(x, y)$, contradicting what we assumed earlier.

Comment: Why do you use proof by contradiction? A direct proof seems to be more elegant: We want to proof that $\forall y\forall x P(x, y)$ follows from $\forall a\forall b P(a, b)$. For that, let $y$ be arbitrary, and also let $x$ be arbitrary. Then we plug in $x$ for $a$ and get $\forall b P(x, b)$. Then we plug in $y$ for $b$ and get $P(x, y)$. QED

Answer (score 1):

The proof is straight forward if, as usually the case in analysis, each quantifier is explicitly restricted to some set as follows:

$\forall a\in X: \forall b \in Y: R(a,b)$

or equivalently...

1. $\forall a:[a\in X \implies \forall b: [b\in Y \implies R(a,b)]]$
2. Suppose $p\in Y$.
3. Suppose further that $q\in X$.
4. From (1), (2) and (3), we have $R(q,p)$
5. From (3), we conclude $\forall a: [a\in X \implies R(a,p)]]$
6. From (2), we conclude $\forall b:[b\in Y \implies \forall a: [a\in X \implies R(a,b)]]$

or equivalently...

$\forall b\in Y: \forall a \in X: R(a,b)$ as required.